# Problems with sorting by date (dd.mm.YYYY) in Datatable using Moment.js and Ordering Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datatables, momentjs

I'm trying to make a Datatable sortable using the method described in [this blogpost](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). As described in the blogpost, I included the two files moment.min.js and datetime-moment.js into my page.

My dates are in the following format: `16.03.2015`

Before initialising the datatable, I am executing moment, like:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('dd.mm.YYYY');

$('.datatable').DataTable({
    "retrieve": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "responsive": true,
    "oLanguage": {
    ......
    ......
```

Unfortunately, the table still gets sorted alphabetically when clicking on the date column. 
I already tried to change "DataTable" in "dataTable" and vice versa - but it doesn't make any difference!
Mabye be I have to specify which column is the column with the date? But I could not find out how to specify it. 
On the Chrome Developer Console there is no error message or log. It just sorts the date column alphabetically all the time. 
I could use a different plugin - but the other one is declared as deprecated. Does anybody know what could be the problem that causes this plugin not to sort the datatable? Thank you!

Comment: Do other date formats work?

Comment: Show how your actual dates look like, maybe they don't match `dd.mm.YYYY` format.

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan : I didn't test other date formats since I'm not free to use other date formats.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com : For example 16.03.2015. I've also tried to use dd.mm.YY with dates like 16.03.15. That doesn't make any difference so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using correct date format `dd.mm.YYYY`, see [Moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). `dd` is day of the week, and `mm` is minutes.

For dates in the format `16.03.2015` use the initialization code below:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');
```